# Match either one of three regexes whichever comes first (in javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, loops

So basically I have a paragraph of words and I have three possible patterns that mark the end of the  paragraph, say regex1, regex2 and regex3 all in the format of /.*?(?=something)/. If none of them exist in the paragraph, I am going to return the entire paragraph. If all exist, I want to match the words before the regex that comes the first. Say if this is the input:

```
 word word word word regex3 word word word regex2 word word regex1
```

I want to return the first four words in this case. If it is:

```
 word word word word regex1 word word word regex3 word word regex2
```

I still want to return the first four words in this case

Another possible input could be:

```
 word word regex1 word word word regex1 word regex2 regex3
```

In this case I just need the first 2 words

One "nasty" way I can think of is to do a whole bunch of nested if else, but this takes forever for my program to run. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird situation but what I would do would be to split your string based on the regexes (I would or them all together into one regex) and then return the first string in the resulting array

So something like

```
thestring.split(/regex1|regex2|regex3/)[0]
```

If your regexes are long and gross you could probably chain the above and still get the same result

```
thestring.split(/regex1/)[0].split(/regex2/)[0]...etc
```

Comment: Using the limit parameter of `String.prototype.split()` may speed up the search (since you only need the first part).

Comment: yea this is faster

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. Suggestions for improvements welcome!

```
var regex1; // = /.*?(?=something)/;
var regex2; // = /.*?(?=something)/;
var regex3; // = /.*?(?=something)/;

function testString(str) {
    var res1 = str.match(regex1);
    var res2 = str.match(regex2);
    var res3 = str.match(regex3);

    // Number.MAX_VALUE = 1.7976931348623157e+308
    if (!res1) res1 = {index: Number.MAX_VALUE};
    if (!res2) res2 = {index: Number.MAX_VALUE};
    if (!res3) res3 = {index: Number.MAX_VALUE};

    var min = Math.min(res1.index, res2.index);
    min = Math.min(min, min3.index);

    return str.substring(0, min);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a [negative lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) for this..

```
var paragraph = "word word word regex1 word regex2 word";
paragraph.match(/^(?:(?!regex1|regex2).)*/);
```

Essentially, as the regex parses your paragraph string, it ensures that whatever comes up next is *not* your terminating case and if it is, it's done.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZQbZV?editors=0010)